# How to store a generated QR code as PNG into the database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

Good day everyone! I'm pretty new to Laravel, and I've been doing a little project with QrCode for about a month.

So my question is: "How do I store a generated QR code into the database in Laravel?"

I have created a function which will create random strings (which act as a unique ID for my assets) and converted into QR code. My next action would be to place the QR code image into my database. I've been following a lot of Laravel tutorial but it's only on uploading image not saving an automatically generated image.

I did save the QR code image inside public folder but it will get overwritten every time I create a new QR code.

This is how I create random strings and convert them into the QR Code and save them

```
$rs = md5(time(). mt_rand(1,100000));
    $assets = Input::all();
    $assets = new Assets;
    $assets->assets_name = Input::get('assets_name');
    $assets->assets_random_string = $rs;


    $assets->save();

    $file = public_path('qr.png');
    \QRCode::text($rs)->setOutFile($file)->png(); 

    return redirect('assets/list')->with('assets', $assets)
```

Please do comment if I've done anything wrong inside my existing so I can improve my code. And let me know if you need anything from my project.

Thank you so much!

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store QR code as image file in to Mysql Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044271/how-to-store-qr-code-as-image-file-in-to-mysql-database)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? As far as I see, you don't store the code in the database after all, which (for a file) wouldn't be recommended after all

Answer (score 0):

Save to content of the QR Code in the DB and generate the QR Code on demand, that should be the best way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already got the random string saved in the same table, I'm going to use this random string as a unique id for assets. 

I intend to save the image so when I'm listing all the assets all unique QRCode based on my random strings will be visible along my assets.

Is it possible to do it? This is my project on Laravel.

Comment: *first project*

Answer (score 0):

The correct way and most optimized way is that you save your file path to qr.png in you database. And once you need to show your QR code you simply pull out the path from you database and attaches it to an HTML img tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already got the random string saved in the same table, I'm going to use this random string as a unique id for assets. 

I intend to save the image so when I'm listing all the assets all unique QRCode based on my random strings will be visible along my assets.

Is it possible to do it? This is my project on Laravel.

Comment: *first project*

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = md5(time(). mt_rand(1,100000));
$assets = Input::all();
$assets = new Assets;
$assets->assets_name = Input::get('assets_name');
$assets->assets_random_string = $rs;

$path = 'images/';
if(!\File::exists(public_path($path))) {
    \File::makeDirectory(public_path($path));
}
$file = $path . time() . '.png';
\QrCode::format('png')->generate($rs, $file);
$assets->file = $file;

$assets->save();
```

`I hope it will works,it works for me.`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?